# Eval Function from a Folder

Tags: matlab, function, eval

I have a function which locally implements a version of a function `g` inside a function `f` stored at `/f/f.m`.

```
% f.m
function f()
% f() body

function y=g(x)
% g() body
##y=g(x);## % Call to g() in /g/g.m
```

Another version of `g`, in another folder of the Matlab Path `/g/g.m`, is required to be called from inside the `g() body`.

`g` is not a builtin function, so `builtin('g',x)` cannot be used.

How should I do this?

Comment: Make this easy on yourself and rename the local function. There is no need to complicate things here.

Comment: your function non-local function `g` will never be seen by your local function`g`, because it already finds a function within its own file (which is of course itself). It *overshadows* the non-local function. This is due to the order, in which MATLAB searches for functions: first the file (i.e. for local functions), than your working directory and than the working path (that is first everything that you added with *add to path* and than the folder with the build-in functions... you can set the order of the path by *Set Path* in the *Home*-tab). So Cris is right: rename your function

Comment: Perhaps removing the current function `f` in folder `f` by using [`rmpath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmpath.html) and calling function `f` in folder `f` by using [`addpath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) could be a way to indicate whether if you want to work with function `f` in folder `f` or you wanted to work with the other `f` located in the other folder `f`!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using folders like `+mypack` or `+mypack/+mysubpack` to organize these functions, see examples from here

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html